# Force windows to use the best graphic card available

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application which has a small 3D Engine on some specific pages (integrated via WindowsFormsHost).

I've seen that on many laptops with several graphic cards (dedicated and integrated) Windows would by default use the integrated one which in many cases will not be good enough to run my 3D Engine.

For example all my games are automatically executed with the dedicated GPU. Is there a way to show windows this WPF application needs the best GPU available ?

I understand that you can change that choice in your graphic card's settings but it's a complicated manipulation for most of the final users.

Comment: This works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504891/laptop-dual-video-cards-how-to-programatically-detect-and-or-choose-which-one

Answer (score 2):

These two threads might be helpful:
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58546/how-can-i-set-my-application-to-run-on-the-high-performance-gpu-by-default

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823372/forcing-machine-to-use-dedicated-graphics-card 
Christopher Oezbek's answer may be of interest

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504891/laptop-dual-video-cards-how-to-programatically-detect-and-or-choose-which-one 
The solution posted by axon seems promising